# elixir-lang Finding non-duplicate elements in a list

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to find non duplicate values from a list e.g.

original list:

```
iex> list = [2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10]
[2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10]

iex> unique = Enum.uniq(list)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

iex> nondupes = unique -- Enum.uniq(list -- unique)
[2, 3, 5, 7]
```

result: [2, 3, 5, 7]

I was wondering if there was a better way to achieve this in elixir/erlang

Answer (score 11):

Another method (not necessarily better) that might be faster for large data is to build a map from elements to their counts and select the ones where count is 1:

```
list
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn (el, acc) -> Dict.put(acc, el, Dict.get(acc, el, 0) + 1) end)
|> Enum.filter(fn {key, val} -> val == 1 end)
|> Enum.map(fn {key, val} -> key end)
```

This should have runtime `O(n * log(n))` instead of the `O(n ^ 2)` your solution requires (the subtraction should be quadratic if the whole input is unique already).

Comment: You can also `reduce` with two sets, one keeping all entries you have seen so far and another with the unique ones. For every item, if it is in the seen list, you should remove it from uniq, otherwise you add to both.

Comment: Just a small improvement: In the reduce step you can also use `&Dict.update(&2, &1, 1, fn x -> x+1 end)` instead of the manual get/put.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: With `elixir 1.10`, you can do this with `frequencies` function.

```
[2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10] 
|> Enum.frequencies 
|> Enum.map(fn {k,v} ->  if v == 1, do: k  end) 
|> Enum.reject( &is_nil/1)
```

OR

```
[2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10] 
|> Enum.frequencies 
|> Enum.filter(fn {_k,v} ->  v == 1  end) 
|> Enum.map( fn {k,_v} -> k  end)
```

With this you can leverage cozy composable pipe operator

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of [José Valim's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33567828/elixir-lang-finding-non-duplicate-elements-in-a-list#comment54914688_33568111), although that suggestion was made before [`Enum.frequencies/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#frequencies/1) was available, and I think [arpit's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63279676/1225617) is simpler and cleaner.

```elixir
list
|> Enum.reduce({MapSet.new(), MapSet.new()}, fn item, {seen, uniq} ->
  case MapSet.member?(seen, item) do
    true -> {seen, MapSet.delete(uniq, item)}
    false -> {MapSet.put(seen, item), MapSet.put(uniq, item)}
  end
end)
|> elem(1)
|> MapSet.to_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

**REDO**

(As Paweł pointed out, I did not answer the question, rather only addressed the uniqifying bit. So I went overboard for fun below.)

Here is a purely recursive, single-pass, matching-only method:

```
-module(nondupes).
-export([leave_uniques/1]).

leave_uniques(L) ->
    lists:reverse(lu(lists:sort(L))).

lu(L = [H,H|_]) -> lu(L, [], dupe);
lu([H|T])       -> lu(T, [H], solo).

lu([H,H], A, dupe)           -> A;
lu([_,H], A, dupe)           -> [H|A];
lu([H,H], A, solo)           -> A;
lu([P,H], A, solo)           -> [P,H|A];
lu([H | T = [H|_]], A, dupe) -> lu(T, A, dupe);
lu([_ | T], A, dupe)         -> lu(T, A, solo);
lu([H | T = [H|_]], A, solo) -> lu(T, A, dupe);
lu([P | T], A, solo)         -> lu(T, [P|A], solo).
```

If past experience is any judge, it is probably more performant on large lists than list/set subtraction -- but past experience also tells me that most of the time performance is really not much of an issue. Anyway, this was sort of entertaining.

Use:

```
2> nondupes:leave_uniques([2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10]).
[2,3,5,7]
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question - this is basically a reimplementation of `Enum.uniq`. Take a look at the question and the expected output of the routine.

Comment: @PawełObrok Indeed. The complete form you want just winds up being what you did, using sets/list operations. So, just to *fully* answer your question in as excruciatingly proper a way as possible, here is a pure routine that extracts unique members in a single pass. Hope it gives you a chuckle.:-)