# Remove duplicate partner values from a list

Tags: elixir

I know that in elixir to remove duplicate values from a list, you need to use `Enum.uniq(my_list)`.

Given a list of `[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]` what will I use for the outcome to be `[2, 4, 5]`. Is there a way not to use nested loops?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [elixir-lang Finding non-duplicate elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33567828/elixir-lang-finding-non-duplicate-elements-in-a-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Enum.frequencies/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#frequencies/1) to calculate how many of each element there are, and then only take items that appear once:

```elixir
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
|> Enum.frequencies()
|> Enum.filter(&match?({_, 1}, &1))
|> Enum.map(&elem(&1, 0))
```

Or, from the linked question, you can use the rather obscure:

```elixir
list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
uniq = Enum.uniq(list)
uniq -- list -- uniq
```